# Is it possible to create a book page flip effect for loading _another_ webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There exist a number of CSS and JavaScript packages, such as `turn.js`, for creating beautiful page flip effects which make it look as if one were leafing through an actual physical book. However, as far as I can see, all of these seem to require that the contents of the complete set of "book pages" be put into a single HTML file.

That way of going about things is, of course, no big deal for small booklets, but for lengthy books with lots of content, it becomes utterly impractical. For one thing, the loading time would simply be too long.

So, my question is: is it possible to engineer a book page flip effect where the flip occurs upon loading a **different** page than the one presently being shown? I would prefer every new page spread (i.e., every verso-recto pair) to have its own webpage. Also, the flip should, of course, be delayed until the new page has finished loading.

Many thanks for reading and for any suggestions!

Comment: Yes, it is, these libraries will have a way to add page on fly... do some research and come again

Comment: To be frank, I have focussed my attention mainly on `turn.js` and BookBlock, and so far, I haven't been able to adapt them to my needs.

Comment: You could use Ajax to load the next book page's content only when needed. (Or perhaps load two or three pages in advance so that there is no delay when the user wants to see the next page, assuming they don't flip too quickly.) I would expect a good page-flip library to have Ajax support built-in.

Comment: +nnnnnn
Yes, that would be an excellent idea. But my current problem is more elementary than that: how do I adapt the basic <div>bookpage 1 content</div><div>bookpage 2 content</div> setup for the situation with new web pages? I have considered using iframes for each half-spread, but that would be very impractical, because I have interactive content, where the left page needs to "talk" to the right. And I understand that this is difficult to orchestrate correctly with iframes.

Comment: Google how to append div, this is kinda basic knowledge... you don't need any iframes

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript wizard like you, just a novice. Anyway, thanks for the advice, I'll look into it.